# Issue with Editing and Saving Data in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am working on a Tkinter application where I have a frame containing labels and entry widgets. The user can edit the data, and there is a save button to save the changes. However, I am facing an issue when attempting to edit and save the data a second time.
After editing and saving once, I encounter difficulties when attempting to edit the same entry again.
The entry widget and save button are not functioning correctly after the initial edit and save.
here is the code of edit_data

```
def save_data(text, i, j):

    global desc_frame
    info = text.get()

    if(len(info)==0):
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "No data to save")
    else:
        text.destroy()
        newinfo = tk.Label(desc_frame, text=info, font=('Helvetica', 15), bg="lightgray")
        newinfo.grid(row=i, column=1, pady=5)
        edit_buttons(i, j+1, newinfo)


def edit_data(newinfo, i, j):
    global desc_frame

    text = newinfo.cget("text")
    if len(text) == 0:
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "No data to edit")
    else:
        newinfo.destroy()
        newEntry = tk.Entry(desc_frame, font=('Helvetica', 15))
        newEntry.insert(0, text)
        newEntry.grid(row=i, column=j - 2, pady=5)
```

and this is the code of the two buttons

```
def save_buttons(i, j, text):

    global desc_frame

    image = Image.open("save3.png")
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("Custom.TButton", background="blue")

    savebtn = ttk.Button(desc_frame, image=image, style="Custom.TButton", command=lambda :save_data(text, i, j))
    savebtn.config(width=4)
    savebtn.image = image
    savebtn.grid(row=i, column=j, pady=5, columnspan=2)


def edit_buttons(i, j, newinfo):

    global  desc_frame

    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("Custom.TButton", background="blue")

    image1 = Image.open("edit.png")
    image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)

    editbtn = ttk.Button(desc_frame, image=image1, style="Custom.TButton", command=lambda : edit_data(newinfo, i, j))
    editbtn.config(width=4)
    editbtn.image = image1
    editbtn.grid(row=i, column=j, pady=5, padx=20, columnspan=2)
```

I  tried this solution in the edit_data function

```
def edit_data(newinfo, i, j):
    global desc_frame

    text = newinfo.cget("text")
    if len(text) == 0:
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "No data to edit")
    else:
        newinfo.destroy()
        newEntry = tk.Entry(desc_frame, font=('Helvetica', 15))
        newEntry.insert(0, text)
        newEntry.grid(row=i, column=j - 2, pady=5)

        existing_save_btn = get_widget_by_row_column(desc_frame, i, j)
        if existing_save_btn:
            existing_save_btn.destroy()
        save_buttons(i, j, newEntry)
```

this is the get_widget_by_row_column function

```
def get_widget_by_row_column(frame, row, column):
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        if widget.grid_info()["row"] == row and widget.grid_info()["column"] == column:
            return widget
    return None
```

this time when I  click on edit button a new saving button appears  but the old one is not destroyed
but do save with the new button .

Comment: consider accepting my answer if it helped. This helps others with similar problems to find a solution faster and keeps the site clean ;)

Answer (score 0):

The save button is not deleted since your `save_data` function does only destroy the entry widget. But instead of deleting and creating the widgets over and over again you could just change their contents. I also refactored your code as an OOP approach since it is more elegant than the `global` variables and also more structured:

```py
from tkinter import ttk, Tk, messagebox


class Gui(Tk):  # own class inheriting from Tk
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # basically the same as root=Tk() but root is now self
        self.desc_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        label = ttk.Label(self.desc_frame)
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, padx=20)
        entry = ttk.Entry(self.desc_frame)
        entry.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5, padx=20)
        self.save_button(1, 0, entry, label)
        self.edit_button(2, 0, entry, label)
        self.desc_frame.pack()

    def save_button(self, i, j, entry, label):
        #image = Image.open("save3.png")
        #image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure("Custom.TButton", background="blue")
        # removed image=image bc I do not have the image, added text='save'
        savebtn = ttk.Button(self.desc_frame, text='save', style="Custom.TButton",
                             command=lambda: self.save_data(entry, label))
        savebtn.config(width=4)
        #savebtn.image = image
        savebtn.grid(row=i, column=j, pady=5, columnspan=2)

    def edit_button(self, i, j, entry, label):
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure("Custom.TButton", background="blue")
        #image1 = Image.open("edit.png")
        #image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
        # removed image=image bc I do not have the image, added text='edit'
        editbtn = ttk.Button(self.desc_frame, text='edit', style="Custom.TButton",
                             command=lambda: self.edit_data(entry, label))
        editbtn.config(width=4)
        #editbtn.image = image1
        editbtn.grid(row=i, column=j, pady=5, padx=20, columnspan=2)

    @staticmethod
    def save_data(entry, label):
        info = entry.get()

        if len(info) == 0:
            messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "No data to save")
        else:
            label.config(text=info)
            entry.delete(0, 'end')

    @staticmethod
    def edit_data(entry, label):
        text = label.cget("text")
        if len(text) == 0:
            messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "No data to edit")
        else:
            entry.insert(0, text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Gui()
    app.mainloop()
```

You should get the idea from here.

Comment: thank you it helped me for completing my project .I apologize for the late reply .

Comment: I'm glad if I could help. Accepting the answer (tick at the top left of my answer) may also help others with the same problem.